# calling several CSS files

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've working on converting Html theme to WordPress and this theme is include several `.CSS` files.

I tried several ways to call them into `head.php` but all unsuccessful!

The ways I tried:

Into `style.css`:

```
@import url('/css/skel.css');
@import url('/css/style.css');
@import url('/css/style-desktop.css');
@import url('/css/style-noscript.css');
```

and for this into `Header.php`:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

## Not worked!

Other way I've tried in `Header.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>css/style-desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>css/style-noscript.css" />
```

## Not worked!

And also used of:

```
stylesheet_url
template_directory
```

## Not Worked!

Additional information:

`Header.php` code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css"/>
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
```

And here is my problem that I found with firebug:

http://prntscr.com/4l5dox

But I'm not sure this is all problems or not :)

So, please what suggest do you have for me?

Thank you.

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory` returns an absolute server path, not a URI. Please see my answer for the correct use of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`. Note that it contains an `echo` and a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use enqueue_style

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Create your own page in theme and include page in functions.php file.

Comment: Change it to [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and I'll give you the +1 ;)

Comment: @giorgio I changed it in wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>css/style.css" />
```

Also it'd be good to see what the output of the above function is, to see if you need to add a slash before css or not.

Or you could just add the file path. Outside of wordpress I don't think these functions work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_stylesheet_directory` returns an absolute server path, not a URI. You'll need to echo `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. Note that this does not return a trailing slash. You'll need to modify your sources by adding them in. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/skel.css" />
```

See the relevant WordPress documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link href="<?php echo home_url('/');?>wp-content/themes/tmeme name/css/css name.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/css name.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first slash from import url's.

```
@import url('css/skel.css');
@import url('css/style.css');
@import url('css/style-desktop.css');
@import url('css/style-noscript.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: No matter what you need the style.css on your base theme folder because wordpress only parse that file for theme metas

```
theme1/style.css
theme1/header.php
theme1/css/other.css
```

In the header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css"/>
```

In the style.css (which needs to contain the theme information)

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme1
Theme URI:
Description: Sample Theme
Author: 
Author URI:
License: GNU General Public License v2.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Version: 1.0
*/

@import url("css/other.css"); //sample css file
```

Comment: can you specified the file structure of your theme folder? im pretty confident this solves your problem. wordpress developer here

Comment: idk if this is causing it or what page are you trying to access, try adding page.php and single.php it is required in wordpress file
work, about, contact pages should not exists, if it is a page, it should be page-work.php, page-about.php, page-contact.php to override the default page.php

Comment: No Roi see these part was include index.html and i made separate of it but i called them as you see in this pic: http://prntscr.com/4l5cki    this is landing page theme i no want to add blog posts or pages (i no need that). everything is ok now except style.

Comment: ok I tried the @import url('/css/style-desktop.css'); and didnt also worked for me, you need to remove the first slash. have you tried it?

Comment: Yes already. And hey look at this i think this must be my problem, these files are not load from theme!!   http://prntscr.com/4l5dox

Comment: what does it look like in your header code? you should be only calling the style.css of the base folder and import everything inside of that style.css in your base folder

Comment: I know! still i'm not work on title or other parts to convert them to WordPress! step by step i need to solve my css problem first then work on other parts. also i want to put theme setting for that. :)  So what do you think about this style-sheet? what should i do with that?

Comment: it should have <?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?> concatinated on it, it has no base url.

Comment: But i don't know where are that two links to change their URL! you see in my head.php have nothing to contact with that 2 files!  I already import them into style.css in my root theme folder but still like that! in <noscript>...</noscript> part they're called but in other part (2 lines above still not!) http://prntscr.com/4l5dox

Comment: this is getting overwhelming really, you need to properly address all the baseline files of a wordpress theme to make everything clean and working.

Comment: try to follow my screenshot then add your customization one by one

Comment: Already buddy, also i changed two part of header.php (see in pic) still nothing changed. http://prntscr.com/4l5sar   I really want to learn this part (how to input several css files)! most of themes like this special responsive and bootstrap themes and i've really problem in this case! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple, in whatever theme folder you are using add this to your functions.php file

```
function add_stylesheets(){ ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css-filepath-inside-theme-folder-here/somefile.css ?>">
```

```
//Add the function to the wordpress head
add_action('wp_head','add_stylesheets');
```

As long as the css files are located near the main style.css file you should be good

Comment: So which one i should use in functions.php? the first one or second one?

Comment: I did it but not worked! this is how i put this codes in functions.php  http://prntscr.com/4lkgfz   and i got this error:   function add_stylesheets(){
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_stylesheets' not found or invalid function name in C:\xamppnew\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 505

Comment: Look at my example closely. Your mixing up where the PHP opening and closing tags.You have closed it before calling the function. You need to close it right after the function opening { and start php perforce the closing } What we are doing is just combining HTML and php. Also in front of your CSS folder add / as it is inside that folder